# Using cmake to detect what system the program is being compiled on

Tags: c, cmake

I have a project written in C that I am porting to an older system `CentOS release 5.10 (Final)`

For our newer system `Fedora 20` we are using `apr-1.5.0`, these won't work on CentSO as I get the link problems there.

```
tools/apr/libs/libapr-1.so: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
tools/apr/libs/libapr-1.so: undefined reference to `epoll_create1@GLIBC_2.9'
tools/apr/libs/libapr-1.so: undefined reference to `dup3@GLIBC_2.9'
tools/apr/libs/libapr-1.so: undefined reference to `accept4@GLIBC_2.10'
```

So I downloaded the older apr-1.2.7 libraries and headers and I compile and link with them and everything works OK.

However, I am using cmake and I have to adjust the path everytime I switch from different operating systems.

For CentOS I have to use this:

```
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/tools/apr-1_2_7/libs)
```

And for a newer system I have to modify and use this:

```
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/tools/apr/libs)
```

I am just wondering if there anyway cmake can detect the system and then use the appropriate libraries.

```
if(CSENTOS_5_10)
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/tools/apr-1_2_/libs)
else
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/tools/apr/libs)
endif
```

I was thinking of creating a toolchain file, but I think that would overkill for just a small thing.

I cannot use the apr that are installed using yum, as there is no guarantee that the libraries and headers have been installed.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: One solution might be to check `/etc/*-release` files. However, there is no real standard there...

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong(tm).

See the docs:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:link_directories

You should be using find_library instead, with hints of where to look for the library.

You can then put such a thing in a Find-module.